# Галерея фоток

Tags: html

Как сделать переключатель меню вот так http://property.az/realpage.php?realID=189822 там фотогаларея

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/

http://highslide.com/

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/

http://www.shadowbox-js.com/index.html

http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/

http://fancybox.net/